# Electric potential due to point charge : Why is dl replaced by dR

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, voltage

I was reading about derivation of electric potential due to a point charge and I was wondering why did they replace $d\vec l $ by $dr\vec a_{R}$

$$Vab = \int _{A} ^{B} \vec E. d\vec l $$

$\vec E$ due to point charge is :

$$\vec E = \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}  \vec a_R$$

Then the electric potential is

$$Vab = \int _{r_A} ^{r_B}  \frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}  \vec a_R. d\vec l $$

Here is where I got stuck why are boundaries now $r_A$ and $r_B$ and why did they replace next

$d\vec l $ by $dr\vec a_{R}$

Comment: Boundaries are determined according to the standard you integrate with ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$d\vec l$ is an arbitrary incremental path which has been replaced by an incremental path along a radial unit vector $\vec a_{\rm R}$ and component $dr$ in that direction.

[image]

This is done because work is only done moving a charge along a radial vector $AC$ and none is done perpendicular to that vector $CB$ because the electric field due to a point charge is radial.

Comment: Why along path CB no work is done?

Comment: What I mean is if I move the charge from C to B rather than from A to C would there be work / electric potential ?

Comment: @HasanHammond No work is done in moving from $C$ to $B$ because the electric field direction is perpendicular  to the arc of radius $r_{\rm B}$.  It is an equipotential line.

Comment: So I could think of it as the charge has spherical layers points on same spherical layer have the same electric potential and no work (as electric work) is done in moving a charge throughout a spherical layer. We do have some mechanical work done thought right? @Farcher

Comment: @HasanHammoud the force due to the electric field is the only force which is acting no work is done when moving along an equipotential.  With no friction no work is done moving a mass along a horizontal surface which is an equipotentail.